# Como validar login con captcha tras intentos fallidos

Tags: php, mysql

Estimados buenas noches.
Estoy realizando un sistema de login con PHP y MYSQL. El objetivo principal es que se valide el número de intentos fallidos cuando el usuario ingresa mal la contraseña, a partir del intento numero 3 se debe mostrar un captcha que debe resolver el usuario. Al intento 5 se bloquea al usuario por sesión y por el momento a modo de prueba se le da un tiempo de bloqueo en la base de datos de 3 minutos. Por el momento solo muestro mensajes para verificar que se estén realizando las validaciones.

Mi problema resulta ser que después del intento numero 3 pongo el captcha en true para que este se muestre, pero al realizar la validación sigue estando en false, entonces no se en que línea debo poner el captcha en false por defecto, para que solo cambie a true dependiendo del número de intentos.
Segundo problema, resulta ser que estoy repitiendo muchas veces la parte del switch, donde se verifica si la cuenta esta activa, inactiva, bloqueada (solo si ya expiro el tiempo de bloqueo) o deshabilitada. Ya que realizo esa validación tanto si el captcha es requerido o si no es requerido.

Y, por último, si la contraseña es incorrecta debo igual validar el captcha si es requerido o no, ¿y si este está bien ingresado?

```
<?php
session_set_save_handler(new \SessionHandler());
session_start();
include dirname(__FILE__).'/logica/conexion/conexion.php';
date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
function intentoFallido($con, $usuario, $intentos) {
    $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Usuario o contraseña inválidos'];
    $tiempobloqueo = 0;
    if($intentos < 2){
        $numero_intentos = $con->actualizar("intentos = intentos + 1","usuarios","correo = ?",[$usuario]);      
    }
    if($intentos >= 2) {
        $numero_intentos = $con->actualizar("intentos = intentos + 1","usuarios","correo = ?",[$usuario]);      
        $captcha = true;
        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Mostrar captcha' , 'error' => 'Tras varios intentos de acceso fallidos, debe resolver el captcha correctamente'];        
    }
    if($intentos >= 5) {
        $tiempobloqueo = time() + 180; // Hora actual + 3 minutos       
        $_SESSION['tiempobloqueo'] = $tiempobloqueo;
        $fechabloqueo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $tiempobloqueo);
        $captcha = true;
        $numero_intentos = $con->actualizar("intentos = intentos + 1, tiempobloqueo = ?, estado = ?", "usuarios","correo = ?",[$fechabloqueo, 'Bloqueada', $usuario]);
      /*  $mensaje = ' Su cuenta ha sido bloqueada temporalmente; podrá volver a intentar hasta: ' . date('d-m-Y H:i', $_SESSION['tiempobloqueo']);*/
        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Ocultar formulario'];
    }
    return $mensaje;
}
$con = new Conexion();
$mensaje = ['mensaje' => ''];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['clave'])){
        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => "Por favor ingrese un usuario y contraseña validos"];
    }else{
        if(isset($_SESSION['tiempobloqueo']) && $_SESSION['tiempobloqueo'] > time()) {
            $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Ocultar formulario'];
        }else{
            $usuario = filter_var(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'usuario'),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $clave = filter_var(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'clave'),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);   
            $datos = $con->obtenerdatos("correo,clave,nombre,apellido,sid,idusuario,intentos,tiempobloqueo,estado","usuarios","correo = ?",array($usuario));
            $mensaje = ['mensaje' => ''];
            $captcha = false;
            if(count($datos) > 0){
                $fila = $datos[0];
                $db_clave = $fila['clave'];
                $db_intentos = $fila['intentos'];
                $db_bloqueo = strtotime($fila['tiempobloqueo']);
                if($db_intentos > 5 && $db_bloqueo > time()){
                    $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Su cuenta sigue bloqueda'];
                }else{
                    if($mensaje['mensaje'] == '' && password_verify($clave,$db_clave)){
                        if($captcha == true){
                            $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Se debe validar captcha'];
                            $valor_captcha = $_SESSION['captcha_text'];
                            $captcha_ingresado = filter_var(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'text-captcha'),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                            if($valor_captcha == $captcha_ingresado){
                                switch ($fila['estado']){
                                    case 'Activa':
                                        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Login correcto'];
                                        break;
                                    case 'Bloqueada':
                                        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Cuenta bloqueda, pero puede iniciar sesion'];
                                        break;
                                    case 'Inactiva':
                                        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Su cuenta aún no a sido activada, revise su bandeja de correo electrónico donde encontrará el link de activación'];
                                        break;
                                    case 'Deshabilitada':
                                        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Su cuenta se encuentra deshabilitada por haber infringido las normas de nuestro sitio, para más detalles póngase en contacto con soporte@ecuservicechile.cl'];
                                        break;
                                }                           
                            }else{
                                $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Captcha incorrecto'];
                            }
                        }else{                          
                            switch ($fila['estado']){
                                case 'Activa':
                                    $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Login correcto'];
                                    break;
                                case 'Bloqueada':
                                    $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Cuenta bloqueda, pero puede iniciar sesion'];
                                    break;
                                case 'Inactiva':
                                    $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Su cuenta aún no a sido activada, revise su bandeja de correo electrónico donde encontrará el link de activación'];
                                    break;
                                case 'Deshabilitada':
                                    $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Su cuenta se encuentra deshabilitada por haber infringido las normas de nuestro sitio, para más detalles póngase en contacto con soporte@ecuservicechile.cl'];
                                    break;
                            }                               
                        }
                    }else{
                        $mensaje = intentoFallido($con, $usuario, $db_intentos);                    
                    }           
                }
            }else{
                $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Usuario o contraseña inválidos'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adjunto el layout del formulario

```
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="new-password">
                                    <div class="form-row justify-content-center mt-3">
                                <?php 
                                if($mensaje['mensaje'] != 'Ocultar formulario'){
                                ?>  
                                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 mb-3">
                                            <label class="label-log" for="usuario">USUARIO</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-log" name="usuario" id="usuario" style="text-transform:upperca;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toLowerCase();" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="new-password">                                      
                                        </div>                                  
                                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 mb-3">
                                            <label class="label-log" for="clave">CONTRASEÑA</label>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-log" name="clave" id="clave" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="new-password">        
                                            <i class="icon-eye mostrar-clave ver-clave"></i>                            
                                        </div>          
                                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 mb-3">
                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success w-100" value="Ingresar" name="submit">                                          
                                        </div>                                  
                                <?php
                                }
                                switch($mensaje['mensaje']){
                                    case 'Mostrar captcha': 
                                ?>
                                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                                            <img src="prueba7.php" alt="CAPTCHA" class="w-100">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                                            <label class="label-log" for="text-captcha">INGRESE EL CAPTCHA</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-log" name="text-captcha" id="text-captcha" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="new-password">  
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                                            <p class="text-white mt-2" id="error"><?php echo $mensaje['error'];?></p>                   
                                        </div>                          
                                <?php
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        ?>                                      
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <p class="text-white mt-2" id="error"><?php echo $mensaje['mensaje'];?></p>                     
                                            </div>                                      
                                        <?php
                                        break;
                                        
                                }
                                ?>      
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

Comment: Para poder ayudar, sería mejor que añades el layout del **captcha**, como lo estas mostrando y ocultando, lo haces mediante PHP y como envías los datos con AJAX o se envía en la misma página?

Comment: Para controlar tu captcha con *true* o *false*, podrías crear algo como esto: ```$captcha = ($intentos >= 3) ? true : false;```, si los intentos son igual a 3 o superior se pone en *true*, mientras seria *false*. Una alternativa seria usar sesiones para mostrar/ocultar el captcha.

Comment: Pregunta editada , agregue el layout de como muestro el captcha, en el archivo que dice prueba7.php que es el scr de la imegen, se genera un captcha aleatorio.

Comment: Revise el código, desde tu función **intentoFallido** solo estas retornando el mensaje (return $mensaje), con lo cual el $captcha = true; no hace nada. Por ese motivo siempre coge la línea de $captcha = false. Yo probaría eliminar todo tus $captcha = true; y también donde inicias el $captcha = false; y añadiría esta línea ```$captcha = ($db_intentos >= 3) ? true : false;``` después de ```$db_bloqueo``` de esta manera la variable $captcha se pone en true o false según los intentos fallidos obtenido desde la BD, y ya debería valorarte si hay 3 intentos fallidos o más ```if($captcha == true){```

Comment: Si hice eso y ahora si me retonar bien el valor del captcha gracias por esa aclaración , lo otro como puedo evitar repetir tanto codigo donde se valida el estado de la cuenta ?

Comment: De nada amigo. déjame revisar esa parte, y te contesto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revise el código, desde tu función `intentoFallido` solo estas retornando el mensaje (return $mensaje), con lo cual el `$captcha = true;` no hace nada. Por ese motivo siempre coge la línea de **$captcha = false**.

Yo probaría eliminar todo tus `$captcha = true;` y también donde inicias el `$captcha = false;` y añadiría esta línea `$captcha = ($db_intentos >= 3) ? true : false;` después de `$db_bloqueo` de esta manera la variable **$captcha** se pone en true o false según los intentos fallidos obtenido desde la BD, y ya debería valorarte si hay 3 intentos fallidos o más `if($captcha == true){`

El switch no hace falta que lo repitas simplemente ponlo antes de la linea del `if($captcha == true){`, te he dejado un posible ejemplo.

También debes resetear el mensaje antes de tu función, sino el return siempre va ser vacío ($mensaje = ['mensaje' => ''];).

**Posible ejemplo:**

```
// Reseteas el mensaje    
$mensaje = ['mensaje' => ''];

function intentoFallido($con, $usuario, $intentos) {
    $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Usuario o contraseña inválidos'];
    $tiempobloqueo = 0;    
    
    if($intentos < 2){
        $numero_intentos = $con->actualizar("intentos = intentos + 1","usuarios","correo = ?",[$usuario]);      
    }
    if($intentos >= 2) {
        $numero_intentos = $con->actualizar("intentos = intentos + 1","usuarios","correo = ?",[$usuario]);      
        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Mostrar captcha' , 'error' => 'Tras varios intentos de acceso fallidos, debe resolver el captcha correctamente'];        
    }
    if($intentos >= 5) {
        $tiempobloqueo = time() + 180; // Hora actual + 3 minutos       
        $_SESSION['tiempobloqueo'] = $tiempobloqueo;
        $fechabloqueo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $tiempobloqueo);
        $numero_intentos = $con->actualizar("intentos = intentos + 1, tiempobloqueo = ?, estado = ?", "usuarios","correo = ?",[$fechabloqueo, 'Bloqueada', $usuario]);
      /*  $mensaje = ' Su cuenta ha sido bloqueada temporalmente; podrá volver a intentar hasta: ' . date('d-m-Y H:i', $_SESSION['tiempobloqueo']);*/
        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Ocultar formulario'];
    }
    return $mensaje;
}

$con = new Conexion();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['clave'])){
        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => "Por favor ingrese un usuario y contraseña validos"];
    }else{
        if(isset($_SESSION['tiempobloqueo']) && $_SESSION['tiempobloqueo'] > time()) {
            $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Ocultar formulario'];
        }else{
            $usuario = filter_var(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'usuario'),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $clave = filter_var(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'clave'),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);   
            $datos = $con->obtenerdatos("correo,clave,nombre,apellido,sid,idusuario,intentos,tiempobloqueo,estado","usuarios","correo = ?",array($usuario));
                            
            if(count($datos) > 0){
                $fila = $datos[0];
                $db_clave = $fila['clave'];
                $db_intentos = $fila['intentos'];
                $db_bloqueo = strtotime($fila['tiempobloqueo']);

                // Creas tu captcha segun intentos BD
                $captcha = ($db_intentos >= 3) ? true : false;

                if($db_intentos > 5 && $db_bloqueo > time()){
                    $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Su cuenta sigue bloqueda'];
                }else{
                    if($mensaje['mensaje'] == '' && password_verify($clave,$db_clave)){

                        switch ($fila['estado']){
                            case 'Activa':
                                $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Login correcto'];
                                break;
                            case 'Bloqueada':
                                $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Cuenta bloqueda, pero puede iniciar sesion'];
                                break;
                            case 'Inactiva':
                                $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Su cuenta aún no a sido activada, revise su bandeja de correo electrónico donde encontrará el link de activación'];
                                break;
                            case 'Deshabilitada':
                                $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Su cuenta se encuentra deshabilitada por haber infringido las normas de nuestro sitio, para más detalles póngase en contacto con soporte@ecuservicechile.cl'];
                                break;
                        }  

                        if($captcha == true){
                            $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Se debe validar captcha'];
                            $valor_captcha = $_SESSION['captcha_text'];
                            $captcha_ingresado = filter_var(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'text-captcha'),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                            if($valor_captcha != $captcha_ingresado){
                                $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Captcha incorrecto'];             
                            }
                        }  

                        // Rediriges a acceso segun comprobaciones
                        //
                        //Primero comprobamos que el estado es activo
                        //luego comprobamos que no existe sesion del capcha y la variable es false.
                        //Damos acceso 
                        //
                        //Con el ||, es decir, OR comprobamos otra regla.
                        //
                        //Primero comprobamos que el estado es activo
                        //Captcha existe
                        //Captcha se verifico correctamente
                        //Damos tambien acceso si todo es correcto
                        if ($fila['estado']== 'Activa' && !isset($_SESSION['captcha_text']) && $captcha == false  || $fila['estado']== 'Activa' && $captcha == true && $_SESSION['captcha_text'] == $captcha_ingresado) {
                           // Rediriges a acceso
                           echo '<script>window.location="/tu_acceso.php"</script>';
                        }
                    }else{
                        $mensaje = intentoFallido($con, $usuario, $db_intentos);                    
                    }           
                }
            }else{
                $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Usuario o contraseña inválidos'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Actualización**

Te he dejado una versión optimizada del código, quitándote algún `if`, `else` etc., hecha le un vistazo, siempre es mejor intentar usar lo menos posible `if`, `else`, `swtich`, etc. y así ordenador bien el código, te ayudará en un futuro si tienes algún problema en el código, te será más fácil resolverlo.

```
<?php
session_set_save_handler(new \SessionHandler());
session_start();
include dirname(__FILE__).'/logica/conexion/conexion.php';
date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");

// Reseteo
$mensaje = ['mensaje' => ''];

function intentoFallido($con, $usuario, $intentos) {
    
    $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Usuario o contraseña inválidos'];
    $tiempobloqueo = (int) 0;    
    
    if($intentos < 2) :
        $numero_intentos = $con->actualizar("intentos = intentos + 1","usuarios","correo = ?",[$usuario]);      
    endif;

    if($intentos >= 2) :
        $numero_intentos = $con->actualizar("intentos = intentos + 1","usuarios","correo = ?",[$usuario]);      
        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Mostrar captcha' , 'error' => 'Tras varios intentos de acceso fallidos, debe resolver el captcha correctamente'];    
    endif;

    if($intentos >= 5) :
        $tiempobloqueo = time() + 180; // Hora actual + 3 minutos       
        $_SESSION['tiempobloqueo'] = $tiempobloqueo;
        $fechabloqueo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $tiempobloqueo);
        $numero_intentos = $con->actualizar("intentos = intentos + 1, tiempobloqueo = ?, estado = ?", "usuarios","correo = ?",[$fechabloqueo, 'Bloqueada', $usuario]);
        //$mensaje = ' Su cuenta ha sido bloqueada temporalmente; podrá volver a intentar hasta: ' . date('d-m-Y H:i', $_SESSION['tiempobloqueo']);
        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Ocultar formulario'];
    endif;
    // Retornar mensaje desde función
    return $mensaje;
}

// Formulario existe
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // form esta vacio
    if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['clave'])) :
        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => "Por favor ingrese un usuario y contraseña validos"];
    // Sesion bloqueo existe
    elseif(isset($_SESSION['tiempobloqueo']) && $_SESSION['tiempobloqueo'] > time()) :
        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Ocultar formulario'];
    else:
        
        // Obtenemos conexión
        //
        // Te aconsejo llamar a la conexión cuando realmente lo vas a usar
        $con = new Conexion();

        // Obtener datos formulario
        $usuario = filter_var(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'usuario'),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $clave = filter_var(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'clave'),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);   
        $datos = $con->obtenerdatos("correo,clave,nombre,apellido,sid,idusuario,intentos,tiempobloqueo,estado","usuarios","correo = ?",array($usuario));
        // Existe datos desde BD   
        if(count($datos) > 0):            

            // Obtener datos BD.
            $fila = $datos[0];
            $db_clave = $fila['clave'];
            $db_intentos = $fila['intentos'];
            $db_bloqueo = strtotime($fila['tiempobloqueo']);

            // Iniciamos variable del captcha en true/false segun intentos obtenidos desde BD
            $captcha = ($db_intentos >= 3) ? true : false;

            // Comprobar bloqueo cuenta
            if ($db_intentos > 5 && $db_bloqueo > time()) :
                    $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Su cuenta sigue bloqueda'];
            // Comprobar contraseña
            elseif ($mensaje['mensaje'] == '' && password_verify($clave,$db_clave)) :

                // Compobamos estado de la cuenta
                switch ($fila['estado']) {
                    case 'Activa':
                        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Login correcto'];
                        break;
                    case 'Bloqueada':
                        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Cuenta bloqueda, pero puede iniciar sesion'];
                        break;
                        case 'Inactiva':
                        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Su cuenta aún no a sido activada, revise su bandeja de correo electrónico donde encontrará el link de activación'];
                        break;
                    case 'Deshabilitada':
                        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Su cuenta se encuentra deshabilitada por haber infringido las normas de nuestro sitio, para más detalles póngase en contacto con soporte@ecuservicechile.cl'];
                        break;
                }  

                // Captcha existe
                if($captcha == true) :
                    $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Se debe validar captcha'];
                    $valor_captcha = $_SESSION['captcha_text'];
                    $captcha_ingresado = filter_var(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'text-captcha'),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                    // Verificamos captcha
                    if ($valor_captcha != $captcha_ingresado) :
                        $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Captcha incorrecto'];             
                    endif;
                endif; 

    
                // Rediriges a acceso segun comprobaciones
                //
                // Comprobamos estado 'activo'
                // Comprobar que no existe sesion del captcha.
                // Todo correcto damos acceso
                //
                // Con el ||, es decir OR comprobamos otra regla.
                //
                // Comprobamos estado 'activo'
                // Captcha si existe
                // Comprobar verificación del Captcha
                // Todo correcto damos acceso tambien.
                if ($fila['estado']== 'Activa' && !isset($_SESSION['captcha_text']) && $captcha == false  ||
                    $fila['estado']== 'Activa' && $captcha == true && $_SESSION['captcha_text'] == $captcha_ingresado) :
                    
                    // Creas sesión del usuario
                    $_SESSION['user'] = [
                        'usuario' => $fila['correo'],
                        'nombre' => $fila['nombre']
                    ];
                    // Rediriges a acceso
                    echo '<script>window.location="/tu_acceso,php"</script>';
                    exit;
                endif;
            // Registramos intentos fallido
            else :
                $mensaje = intentoFallido($con, $usuario, $db_intentos); 
            endif;
        // Usuario invalido
        else:
            $mensaje = ['mensaje' => 'Usuario o contraseña inválidos'];
        endif;        
    endif;
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="new-password">
    <div class="form-row justify-content-center mt-3">
<?php 
    if($mensaje['mensaje'] != 'Ocultar formulario') :
?>  
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 mb-3">
            <label class="label-log" for="usuario">USUARIO</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-log" name="usuario" id="usuario" style="text-transform:upperca;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toLowerCase();" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="new-password">                                      
        </div>                                  
    
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 mb-3">
            <label class="label-log" for="clave">CONTRASEÑA</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-log" name="clave" id="clave" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="new-password">
            <i class="icon-eye mostrar-clave ver-clave"></i>                            
        </div>          
        
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 mb-3">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success w-100" value="Ingresar" name="submit">                                          
        </div>                                  
<?php
    endif;

    switch($mensaje['mensaje']){
        case 'Mostrar captcha': 
?>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <img src="prueba7.php" alt="CAPTCHA" class="w-100">
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <label class="label-log" for="text-captcha">INGRESE EL CAPTCHA</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-log" name="text-captcha" id="text-captcha" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="new-password">  
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <p class="text-white mt-2" id="error"><?php echo $mensaje['error'];?></p>                   
        </div>                          
<?php
            break;
        default:
?>                                      
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <p class="text-white mt-2" id="error"><?php echo $mensaje['mensaje'];?></p>                     
        </div>                                      
<?php
            break;
    }
?>      
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Tengo una duda, como habia mencionado por el momento solo muestro mensajes, pero en la practica si todo sale correcto en la parte del switch si la cuenta esta Activa, el login debería ser correcto y redirigir  la pagina correspondient  creando las variables de sesion, pero que pasa si ingreso mal el captcha, igual me dejaria pasar

Comment: @JonathanAlarcon te he actualizado mi respuesta como crear acceso si todo está correcto, existen dos posibilidades si existe el captcha y cuando no (```if ($fila['estado']== 'Activa' && !isset($_SESSION['captcha_text']) && $captcha == false  || $fila['estado']== 'Activa' && $captcha == true && $_SESSION['captcha_text'] == $captcha_ingresado) {//acceso}```)

Comment: @JonathanAlarcon Te soluciono el problema mi respuesta?

Comment: Hola, no había tenido tiempo de responder, sii, solo hice una pequeña modificación, pero si me funcionó, muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: @JonathanAlarcon me alegro amig@, te he dejado una versión optimizada del código, así te será más fácil entenderlo, no lo he probado personalmente.